# 1988 nx Honda 250 No start has fuel, compression, spark

Tags: honda, electrical, motorcycle, cranks-wont-run, rectifier

I had to wire the bike up myself bypassed the ignition, lights an all that to get it to spark got a brand new carburetor for it I have half the exhaust off so when its cranking sometimes it will shoot fire out the exhaust, or it will just have steam coming out. Also when your giving it gas while cranking it the cranking starts getting real fast like its about to start then goes back to its normal cranking speed. The timing is spot on so what could it be?  Rectifier possibly? Idk but please someone help me out I been trying to fix this for months now

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How did you verify the timing is "spot on". From the sounds of it, this is the first place I'd be looking considering your description.

Comment: Does "brand new carburetor" mean new and unused, or second-hand? If new, is it the right one for a 35-year-old machine?

Comment: Spinning up faster than normal may mean compression loss. Remove the spark plug and examine it for raw fuel to be sure fuel is getting into the cylinder. Add a squirt of motor oil into the cylinder to help with compression, put the plug back in and try starting again.

Comment: Has the bike ever run while in your possession?

Comment: No it hasn't ran while it's been in my possession I made sure the piston was on the compression stroke when I timed it. I bought the carburetor brand new but it's a no name brand looks just like the original it said it would work I figured I'd give it a shot because for a used one that came off another nx they want 200 bucks for at the moment I couldn't afford that I'll try the oil trick an get back to you thanks for the advice everyone

Comment: Paulster2 I made sure it was at top dead center on the compression stroke like the owners Manuel said made sure the two lines on the side of the timing chain sprockets were both even an the t at the bottom was right on its mark